# How Data Transfer is calculatedin AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I was going through the AWS s3 calculator for `Standard Storage`. I didnt understood the meaning of `Data Transfer` calculation. How it is calculated?

```
Data Transfer:
Inter-Region Data Transfer Out: 10GB/Month
Data Transfer Out:10GB/Month
Data Transfer In:10GB/Month
Data Transfer Out to CloudFront:
```

Let say my use case is i want to upload a file, store it in S3 s long as i want it, i will download it whenever i want, i will modify the file and these operation i will do from across the world from mobile, laptop through my app/website.

Answer (score 1):

You pay for all traffic going out of AWS (Data Transfer Out). You also pay for inter-region traffic.

Let's say you have a S3 bucket in Virginia and an EC2 in Oregon. This EC2 downloads a 100MB file from that bucket. You'll pay 100MB of inter-region.
If you download the file from your PC, you pay 100MB of transfer out. You always pay for what goes out or to another region. If you partially download a file, you'll be charged that exact amount. That's basically it.

Comment: why i dont see these prices in azure or google cloud?

Comment: Azure charges for transfer out as well. In the calculator, you have to add “Bandwidth”. SoftLayer/Bluemix also does. I don’t know about Google though.

Comment: @manish just search for the traffic pricing, Google Cloud has more or less the same price level as AWS (I believe IBM is not far behind too).. 10GB/month is almost negligible, but any video streaming service needs to count with these costs. Low cost providers are charging much less for traffic, but the TCO may pop up somewhere else.